# Javascript visual design issue

Tags: javascript

I have been making a javascript program thing and now I am at the stage where I need to make it visual. I have an idea of what It should look like but Dont know the best way to go about it. I could just put images and change them when needed, but I am wondering do I have to refresh the page everytime I want to change something?

Here is what I want it to look like, whats the best way to go about this. Just javascript no jquery etc.

http://postimg.org/image/p4nnnmqap/

Comment: JavaScript is for behavior; HTML is for structure and content; CSS is for styling. Look into the latter two, especially CSS.

Comment: How did you make a "javascript program thing" without ever viewing it in a browser ?

Comment: @adeneo: There are non-browser JavaScript engines. For example, Node.js.

Comment: @icktoofay - I doubt the OP has installed, configured and made a "javascript program thing" in Node, and now has no idea how to make it "visual" ?

Comment: I suggest you look into the very basics of creating dynamic pages with Javascript, HTML and CSS. There is so much on the web to find about. Maybe this is a good starting point: http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: @Flaxfield - We all love W3Fools, what a great site!

Comment: @adeneo Well... still for a very first step it is not so bad.. i think... What do you think is a good starting point for the very novice? Just to keep this constructive.

Comment: @adeneo: Very true, but it *could happen…*

Comment: Download jQuery, it makes stuff "visual" ?

Comment: would that make it a jQuery program thing?

Answer (score 0):

You may use **SetInterval()** to refresh, if you want to...
Your program is running in what plataform and what language?
Long time ago i made one HTML WYSIWYG editor in **Delphi7**, and using the *TWebBrowser* as a viewer, and with the save button, had a function to also refresh the *TWebBrowser*, worked fine.
But if your workspace runs directly to a HTML page you can just set an interval of 60000ms to refresh the viewr every 1 minute.t

Comment: There's even an outdated meta tag to do this, but why would you willingly refresh a page every minute ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to build the structure in HTML and let Javascript fill in the dynamic parts on the fly.

It could be as simple as having simple `<span>` placeholders.

```
<span id="count">0</span> <!-- initial value = 0 -->
```

And update it with

```
document.getElementById('count').innHTML = '987';
```

**P.s. Always make sure the DOM element exists before the code executes.**